# Simple union conversion example - C to C#

Tags: c#, c, arrays, pinvoke, unions

I am trying to use a DLL written in C in a C# application. I've created a simplified example that replicates the issue I am having.

The C code below creates an array of `struct data`'s and assigns the array pointer to the `array` parameter passed to the `get_data()` function. The C# code is supposed to be the boilerplate code needed for marshalling the struct to be used in C#, but is presenting issues for me.

#### C code

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct data {
    int32_t value;
    union {
        struct person {
            uint8_t first[10];
            uint8_t last[10];
        } person;
        struct number {
            int32_t imaginary;
            int32_t real;
        } number;
    } type;
};

int get_data(int count, struct data ***array)
{
    int i;

    /* allocate pointers */
    *array = calloc(count, sizeof(struct data*));
    if (*array == NULL)
        return 1;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        /* allocate data struct */
        struct data *data = calloc(1, sizeof(struct data));
        if (data == NULL)
            return 2;

        if ((i % 2) == 0) {
            /* if even, its human */
            data->value = i;
            memcpy(data->type.person.first, "john", 4);
            memcpy(data->type.person.last, "doe", 3);
        } else {
            /* if odd its a number */
            data->value = i;
            data->type.number.imaginary = -1;
            data->type.number.real = i + 1;
        }

        (*array)[i] = data;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### C# code

```
[DllImport("libdata.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern Int32 get_data(Int32 count, ref IntPtr array);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Person
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 10)]
    public String first;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 10)]
    public String last;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Number
{
    public Int32 imaginary;
    public Int32 real;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct TypeUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Person person;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Number number;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Data
{
    public Int32 value;
    public TypeUnion type;
}
```

Right now when I run my test program I get an exception:

```
System.TypeLoadException was unhandled
  Message=Could not load type 'WpfRibbonApplication1.TypeUnion' from assembly 'WpfRibbonApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 0 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.
```

I have tried several different ways of marshalling the `Person` strings, but get the exception whichever way I try (using [this](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84519/mastering-structs-in-c/) as reference). Am I missing something obvious? Could I get some help to properly read the array created in the C function within my C# application?

#### Edit (per David Heffernan's comment)

```
IntPtr arrayPtr = new IntPtr();
int count = 4;
int ret = LibData.get_data(count, ref arrayPtr);
Console.WriteLine("ret=" + ret);

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    IntPtr dataPtr = (IntPtr)Marshal.ReadIntPtr(arrayPtr) + (i * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)));
    Data data = (Data)Marshal.PtrToStructure(dataPtr, typeof(Data));
    Console.WriteLine("value=" + data.value);
    if ((i % 2) == 0)
    {
        // even is human
        Console.WriteLine("first=" + data.type.first);
        Console.WriteLine("last=" + data.type.last);
    }
    else
    {
        // odd is number
        Console.WriteLine("imaginary=" + data.type.imaginary);
        Console.WriteLine("real=" + data.type.real);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Comment: At which point in the code does the error message appear?

Comment: When I call `Data data = (Data)Marhsal.PtrToStructure(dataPtr, typeof(Data));`. I omitted that code simply to keep the question as short as possible. If you would like to see it I can edit the question.

Comment: I think that part of the code is important. Should be in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that you cannot overlay an object field with a non-object field. You are overlaying a `string` with an `int`.

There's no way you are going to get around that using `FieldOffset` to replicate the native union. As I see it you have two main options:

1. Stop using a union and include both `Person` and `Number` structs in the `Data` struct.
2. Continue using a union, but marshal it yourself. Use the `Marshal` class to read the data in the struct. For example, you'd use `Marshal.ReadInt32` to read the integers, `Marshal.Copy` to read the character arrays and so on.